# Detecting float type

Tags: floats

I'm writing a small package and I need to detect the type of float. The action will be one if the macro expands in a figure float and another if a table float is detected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a minimal not quite working example - a complete compilable short document that illustrates what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 5):

```
\@captype
```

will be defined to be `figure` or `table` (or whatever other float type has been defined)

Comment: I tried \ifx\@captype{figure} Unfortunately, it didn't works. What did I do wrong? –

Comment: @OtavioGomes that is not how `\ifx` works. You could do something like `\def\@tempa{figure}\ifx\@captype\@tempa`.